# GeoServer - Preseeded tiles don't match given Bounding Box

Tags: coordinates, geoserver, bounding-box

I'm trying to seed some tiles but GeoServer only returns empty output, as it seems to not match
the given bounding box.
This is how i set it up:
[image]

The bounding box is obtained via http://bboxfinder.com/#40.446947,0.175781,42.908160,3.339844
where i copied the `Box` label data from EPSG:4326 tab:

[image]`

At that zoom level, all generated tiles should start by 13X.XXX, like for example:

```
18/132647/97891.geojson
18/132648/97891.geojson
```

But GeoServer output starts with 26X.XXX:

```
EPSG_4326/18/267008/72147.geojson
EPSG_4326/18/267008/72151.geojson
EPSG_4326/18/267008/72155.geojson
EPSG_4326/18/267008/72159.geojson
EPSG_4326/18/267008/72163.geojson
EPSG_4326/18/267008/72167.geojson
```

So all tiles/files are empty.

What i'm doing wrong? What am i missing out?

Comment: did you clear the cache before you started?

Comment: @IanTurton how will cache change the generated XY tiles? :o :S
Where/How can i delete that cache?

Comment: Just delete the folders containing the tiled

Comment: Oh i already did that the first time they were wrong, but they got recreated equally wrong in each try.